# Получить абсолютные пути ко всем файлам в дереве директорий

Tags: python, файлы, файловая-система

Я не нашёл функцию ни в `glob`, ни в `os`, которая возвращает все файлы дерева каталогов. Есть ли такая функция? Если да, то приведите её. Если нет, то приведите Вашу реализацию получения всех абсолютных путей до файлов, начиная с заданной директории.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory

Comment: @entithat Прочитайте ещё раз вопрос. Рекурсивно

Comment: os.walk() ведь возвращает все каталоги подкаталоги и файлы возвращает

Comment: Он возвращает их в разнобой и их руками приходится группировать.

Comment: Ну да чуть поработать надо руками

Comment: pathlib с Path.rglob() тоже не поможет?

Comment: @Александр поэтому я и задал вопрос, чтобы работа руками больше не повторялась: сохранить в одном месте.

Comment: @strawdog да, это помогло. Я запилил в ответ. Можете вы подробнее расписать и я приму Ваш

Comment: Вы привели бы наглядный пример, например, с tree - пару директорий с парой файлов и желаемый результат. Вопрос меняется каждые пять минут и не совсем понятно, что вам нужно.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Используя [glob.glob()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/glob.html#glob.glob):

```
files = [os.path.abspath(f) for f in glob.glob(f"{path}/**/*")]
```

Используя [pathlib.Path.rglob()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#Path.rglob):

```
files = [str(f.absolute()) for f in Path(path).rglob("*")]
```

Используя [pathlib.Path.glob()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#Path.glob):

```
files = [str(f.absolute()) for f in Path(path).glob("**/*")]
```

---

Импорт класса `Path` вне зависимости от версии Python:

```
try:
    from pathlib import Path       # Python 3.x
except ImportError:
    from pathlib2 import Path      # Python 2.x  (pip install pathlib2)
```

Comment: @0xdb, честно говоря, я не понял зачем автор изменил в последней редакции заголовок от `insolor` - тот был явно лучше и подробнее

Comment: если заголовок написан лакончино, то большее количество людей сможет его найти. Длинные заголовки мало кто ищет и найти их сложнее

Comment: @hedgehogues, весьма спорное утверждение. Не хотел бы я видеть на SO вопросы с заголовками: "Проблема", "Ошибка", "Путь", "Файл" и т.д. Советую ознакомиться: ["Как задать хороший вопрос?"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @hedgehogues поиск происходит не по точному совпадению заголовка, а по ключевым словам, входящим в заголовок и текст вопроса/ответа. В поисковой выдаче видно полный заголовок и только кусок тела. Если заголовок наиболее полно описывает проблему, то это более удобно для того кто ищет ответ на свой вопрос.

Comment: @insolor но Вы не учитываете, что разрастание заголовка (особенно, если есть несколько значимых слов), сильно уменьшает его важность по отдельным словам.

Comment: @hedgehogues, не учитываю. Я учитываю здравый смысл: если заголовок не описывает суть вопроса - это плохой заголовок. Если из заголовка вообще не понятно о чем вопрос (например "Получить все файлы" - откуда получить, из интернета все файлы скачать?), то это очень плохой заголовок.

Answer (score 4):

Один из самых компактных способов:

```
from pathlib import Path
files = []
for p in Path(path).rglob('*'):
    files.append(str(p.parent)+p.name)
```

Comment: Похоже, вы нашли ответ раньше, чем я написал комментарий. Так что, принимайте свой ответ )

Comment: @strawdog мне всегда приятнее принять чей-нибудь ответ, чем мой собственный (=. Так что я подожду.