# Как проверять наличие определённых файлов в папке и если они есть, то делать с ними какие то операции? Также в описании

Tags: python, файлы, библиотеки

**Python 3.10**

У меня есть папка, в ней много других папок и т.д.,
мне нужно чтобы код искал среди этих всех папок много одинаковых с одинаковыми названиями, то есть пробегался по папкам, ищя определённые названия, если эти названия есть, то чтобы код копировал их в другое место.

Также, эти все файлы находятся во множестве папок, названия которых я не знаю, они по типу "`Hd84nG84184ty`" - и т.д. рандомно, то есть я не знаю по какому пути искать файлы

(`C:/Users/Admin/Papcka/<НеизвестноеНазвание>/НужныйФайл`) - примерно так.

Comment: И что у вас не получается?

Comment: На SO полно вопросов и ответов же про модули `os`, `glob` и т.д.

Comment: вполне себе дубликаты: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1256090/178576), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1124747/178576)

Comment: [3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1141392/234134)